# How to make text update on the canvas after a button click in tkiner

Tags: python, class, button, tkinter

I want to make a "shop" and once you click a certain button it will subtract however much gold it cost for that. The problem I am facing is refreshing the canvas after you click the button so it shows how much gold you have.

```
class Hi:
    gold=100
    def showShop(self):
        def buyArcher():
            Hi.gold = int(Hi.gold) - 10
            updateScreen(canva)

        def updateScreen(name: Canvas):
            self.name = name
            self.name.update_idletasks()

        canva = Canvas(root, width="750", height="750",bg="brown")
        button1 =Button(root,text="Hello", command=buyArcher)
        button1.configure(width=10, activebackground="#33B5E5", relief=FLAT)
        button1_window = canva.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1)
        label = Label(text=Hi.gold, width=10)
        label.configure(width=10, activebackground="brown", relief=FLAT)
        label_window = canva.create_window(700, 10, anchor=NW, window=label)
        canva.pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

I expect the gold to change from 100 to 90 on the screen after a button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little skeleton that you can maybe expand upon to build your game.

It has a `class Player`, a `class Shop`, and a `class Item`; it keeps a gold balance for the player, and refuses to spend when the savings are insufficient. It keeps a rudimentary item inventory for both the player and the shop; the shop cannot sell items that it does not have.

You can purchase items by clicking on the corresponding element on the canvas, and the remaining gold amount is displayed.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, gold=100):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = 100
        self.items = []
    def pay_gold(self, amount):
        if self.gold >= amount:
            self.gold -= amount
            goldvar.set(self.gold)
            return True
        return False

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Player: {self.name} posessions: \n\t' + '\n\t'.join(f'{item.name}' for item in self.items) + f'\n\tgold: {self.gold}'


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name


class Shop:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items[:]
    def buy_item(self, item):
        if item in self.items and player.gold >= item.price:
            if player.pay_gold(item.price):
                self.items.remove(item)
                player.items.append(item)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'shop inventory:\n\t' + '\n\t'.join(f'{item.name} at {item.price}' for item in self.items)


archer = Item('Archer', 10)
sword = Item('Sword', 15)
shop = Shop([archer, sword, archer, sword, archer, sword, archer, sword, archer, sword, archer, sword])
player = Player('Henryk')

print(shop)
print(player)

print()
shop.buy_item(archer)

print(player)
print(shop)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="750", height="750", bg="brown")
button_sword = tk.Button(root, text="sword", command=lambda item=sword: shop.buy_item(item))
button1_window = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor=tk.NW, window=button_sword)
button_archer = tk.Button(root, text="archer", command=lambda item=archer: shop.buy_item(item))
button2_window = canvas.create_window(10, 30, anchor=tk.NW, window=button_archer)


goldvar = tk.IntVar()
goldvar.set(player.gold)
label = tk.Label(root, width=10)
label.configure(width=10, relief=tk.FLAT, textvariable=goldvar)
label_window = canvas.create_window(600, 10, anchor=tk.NW, window=label)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```